# Writing Databricks dataframe to BLOB storage

Tags: azure-databricks

I am using Azure databricks and have a mounted BLOB store.
I tried saving my dataframe into there using:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").csv("/mnt/gl")
```

and  I got the following error:

```
 shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1181559690773266> in <module>()
----> 1 df.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").csv("/mnt/gl")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue)
    927                        charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
    928                        encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue)
--> 929         self._jwrite.csv(path)
    930 
    931     @since(1.5)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
```

Update:
Error now says 'Job Aborted' after I recreated the SAS key

Comment: is your mount dir working well? try to do dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/gl'), is it working?

Comment: This worked for me. (Handy bit of code to know too)

Comment: have you been able to figure this out; I'm having the same problem @user1761806

Comment: I just recreated the Databricks cluster and it started working again

Answer (score 0):

try to change your "csv" to "save":

```
df \
.write \
.mode("overwrite") \
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
.option("header","true") \
.save("/mnt/gl")
```

Comment: This didn't work either. It said Job Aborted followed by a Py4JJavaError. I also got this error using my way I recreating the SAS_Key